# Run one macro on cell click and a different macro on cell double-click

Tags: excel, vba, click, double-click

I have a database with category headers that contain .Interior.Color and .Font formatting which is applied to selected rows, when the category header cells are clicked.

I want to add the functionality that when a category header cell is double-clicked, all rows in the document that do not match that category will be hidden.

I added the following to my Sheet1 (Code):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, HideRow As 
Boolean)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C1:W1")) Is Nothing Then
    LstRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), lookat:=xlPart, _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _ 
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row   
    'Finds last row with data
    Set Dyn_AllEntries = ActiveSheet.Range("C5:C" & LstRow)  'range w/ all data
    If HiddenRows <> True Then  'Checks to see if the macro was already run
        For Each cl In Dyn_AllEntries
            If cl.Offset(0, 11) <> Target Then  'check if category matches
                cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True   'if not, hide row
            End If
        Next cl
        HiddenRows = True   'set boolean, to verify the macro is active
    ElseIf HiddenRows = True Then  'check if macro is active
        For Each cl In Dyn_AllEntries
            If cl.Offset(0, 11) <> Target And LCase(cl.Offset(0, -2)) <> _ 
            "true" Then  'if category not match & row not hidden by other macro
                cl.EntireRow.Hidden = False   'unhide row
            End If
        Next cl
        HiddenRows = False    'set boolean so I know macro isn't active
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Now, the code I wrote for when a cell is selected is giving me an error on compile:

> Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

My "single-click" code is named `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range, HideText As Boolean)` and my "double-click" code is named `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, HideRow As Boolean)`.

Both are within the Sheet1 (Code) module. My "single-click" code has not changed, since it was working before I added the "double-click" code.

Is it not possible to run two different macros of the same cell, for different selection actions?

Here's what the sheet looks like, if that helps: [image: Sheet1]

Comment: Those events don't support the `HideText As Boolean` argument and `HideRow As Boolean` argument. In the code you provided, `HideRow` is not used at all, but `HiddenRows` is - related?

Comment: Both will throw the same compile error. There's no way that the "single-click" code was working before if it included the `HideText` argument.

Comment: Moving my Boolean dimensioning into the code (instead of the sub heading) and matching the variable name for "HiddenRows" fixed my problem. Thank you both, so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can't change event handler signatures as you please - that's not how events work.

Worksheet events are defined in some `WorksheetEvents` interface, and the method signatures are what they are and they're set in stone: the event source (i.e. the worksheet) is what's providing the values for the parameters - how will the worksheet know what value to provide for this `HideRow` argument? It won't, and since the `Worksheet` module you're in is inheriting its members from the `Worksheet` class, if you name a procedure `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` in a worksheet module then because VBA doesn't support *method overloading* the only way to get that to compile is to have that procedure have the exact* same signature it's defined with.

Make the event handler signatures match the signatures they are expected to have, and the code will compile again.

*almost: the parameter *names* don't really matter - their type, and their order, does.

Comment: Ironically, I am able to get the code to compile as long as I add any boolean to the event name (including HideRow), but removing them causes the code to fail to compile. I currently have a made up and unused boolean declared in the parentheses so it will compile. ::shrugs::

Also, I'm unable to find any information on event handler signatures, event signatures, or even a decent article on members inherited from the worksheet class. Would you have a suggested place for me to educate myself on those things?

Thanks!

Comment: The object browser (F2), and the two dropdowns in the code pane.

Comment: @Casey the code may compile, but pay attention to the dropdowns at the top of the code pane: if it says "(general)" in the left one, it's not an event handler - just a procedure that will never run ;-)